# The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)

Tags: deno

I am using deno for the first time and `The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)` is the error I am getting. My code below:-

```
import { Application } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts'

const app = new Application();
const port = 3000;

app.use((ctx) => {
    ctx.response.body = "Hello World"
})

app.listen({ port })
console.log(`localhost:${port}`)
```

I am using `deno run --allow-net .\server.js` on powershell to start deno. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** If I try to do a simple console.log and run the file with `deno run server.js` it runs fine which mean that the deno environment is setup correctly. As soon as I add the import statement at the top, the error starts happening.

Comment: Hm.. I tried it on my mac and it works just fine. What does `deno --version` give you?

Comment: it says `1.0.3`

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be that you have a cached version of `oak` for an old version of `deno`.

do:

```
deno cache --reload server.js
```

And then run your server again:

```
deno run --allow-net server.js
```

---

It is considered a bad practice to use non-versioned URL, but in this case since there's no new version released yet for deno `1.0.3` you don't have a choice but to use `master`.

---

**UPDATE**: The error might be fixed by [PR #6000](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/6000)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. After some tries, I see that there is different betwwen nodejs and deno when use import. In node, we use this

```
import { Server } from './Server';
```

But in deno we use

```
import { Server } from './Server/index.js
```

It resolved my issue, hope is the same for you

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error. I did the following steps to resolve this error:

1. If you have Visual Studio open, **first close it.**
2. Open your command(**cmd**) prompt  **Run as Administrator**
3. Run this command `scoop install deno`
4. Now open Visual Studio Code and Run Your Program using this command:

   ```
   deno run --allow-net --allow-read --allow-write ./server.js
   ```

   or

   ```
   deno run --allow-net --allow-read --allow-write .\server.js
   ```