# error: Failed to get compiled source code of https://deno.land/std@0.59.0/path/mod.ts. Reason: The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)

Tags: typescript, ejs, deno

After running my `main.ts` file with `deno` I get this error:

```
error: Failed to get compiled source code of https://deno.land/std@0.59.0/path/mod.ts.
Reason: The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)
```

I am running my file with this command: `deno run --allow-net  main.ts` and I also tried `deno run --allow-net --allow-read  main.ts` but same error occurs.

My `main.ts` file:

```
// Requiring modules 
import { Application, Router,send } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
import {viewEngine,engineFactory,
adapterFactory} from "https://deno.land/x/view_engine/mod.ts";

// Initiate app
const app = new Application();
const router = new Router();

// Setting up boilerplate for view-engine
const ejsEngine = await engineFactory.getEjsEngine();
const oakAdapter = await adapterFactory.getOakAdapter();

// Passing view-engine as middleware
app.use(viewEngine(oakAdapter,ejsEngine));

// Adding middleware to require our router
app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

// Creating Routes
router.get("/", (ctx) => {
    ctx.render('index.ejs', {data: {msg: "World"}})
})

// Making app to listen to port
console.log('App is listening to port: 8000');
await app.listen({port:8000});
```

And an example of `index.ejs` file

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Serving HTML</title> 
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1> Hello <%= data.msg %></h1> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I run ```deno cache --reload main.ts``` I also get the same error. I also tried answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62124334/11322237) but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open issue regarding this: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/6628

For the time being after trying a couple of times without `--reload`, `path` was compiled correctly and I was able to run the script correctly.

As a workaround, you can create a `test.ts` file and after you execute it, you'll have `path` downloaded and compiled correctly in the cache.

```
import * as path from 'https://deno.land/std@0.59.0/path/mod.ts'
```

Run

```
deno run test.ts
```

and then

```
deno run --allow-net  main.ts
```

Comment: Even with that issue apparently fixed, I still get it on my Mac:

Warning Failed to get compiled source code of "https://deno.land/x/denjucks@1.1.1/src/deps/path/std/path/mod.ts".
Reason: No such file or directory (os error 2)